# Custom port problem with local MU installation

Tags: multisite, wp-config

#### Situation

I've just setup a new installation of WordPress (running on XAMPP/Win7). As I had a port conflict on `:80/:443`, I switched to `:187/4430`.

#### Error

When I'm now trying to access `http://vanilla-mu.dev:187/index.php` (or any other request), then I run into the following WordPress Error inside a `wp_die()` page:

> *`Multisite only works without the port number in the URL.`*

#### Question

As I know that the error is non resolvable according to ticket [#21077](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21077), I need to somehow change my setup. How could I work around this? What would be a setup that accounts the fact that there's a port conflict, but doesn't run into the core bug?

#### The setup

```
// ~\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf
Listen 187
ServerName 127.0.0.1:187

// ~\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 vanilla-mu.dev

// ~\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf
## vanilla-mu.dev
<VirtualHost *:187>
    ServerName www.vanilla-mu.dev
    ServerAlias vanilla-mu.dev
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\vanilla-mu.dev"
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\vanilla-mu.dev">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +Includes
        AllowOverride FileInfo
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.shtml index.html index.htm
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/error_vanilla-mu.log"
    CustomLog "logs/access_vanilla-mu.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**EDIT:** *Additional info for later readers to identify possible conflicts.*

### Port conflict available?

First hit your `Win` Start Button and open the command line interface typing `cmd`. Then type the following line, followed by the port number to check (`80` and `443`).

```
netstat -o -n -a | findstr 0.0:80
netstat -o -n -a | findstr 0.0:443
```

You will then see the process(es) ID(s) that are currently using the questioned port.

> [image]

#### Identify a port conflict and what is causing it

The next thing to do is to right click on your menu bar and open the `Taskmanager`. The `Taskmanager` by default doesn't show the PID. I added a screenshot that shows you how you can add it.

> [image]

*The question still remains.*

Comment: Cant you make the xamp listen on 127.0.0.2 ?

Comment: @chifliiiii Good question. Dunno, but I guess yes. What would that change for me?

Comment: What domain it listens on is irrelevant if it has to listen on port 80 first

Comment: I think you'll have more luck on [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com/) - this is really straying from WP!

Comment: @TheDeadMedic You're absolutely right, but the problem is (as TomJNowell stated and as you can read in the trac ticket) a problem WordPress has in core. And as it isn't solved so far, I'll leave the question here. I also added the tag [tag:trac], so we can file other questions under the same ticket. I guess it will help some other people as there's close to no source available.

Comment: Well if you listen on another ip, then you can use the port 80 if the conflict is on 127.0.0.1:80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the question itself, this is a problem a non-solvable due to the internals of WP core.

What I did was getting rid of the interfering/colliding process - I simply turned it off (as changing the port wasn't possible).

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered another (non WP) problem: Skype using port 80/443. This problem will only apply if Skype starts *before* XAMPP (or whatever local server you're using).

To fix it go into "tools " then "options" and connection down the left, untick the box "use port 80 and 443 as alternative incomming ports".

[image]